# Shift selection in Emacs 24 does not highlight text

Tags: emacs

I must be stupid, but I just switched to Emacs 24, and holding Shift while moving the point no longer highlights text. Mouse selection works as before. What am I missing? Did I turn it off by chance? Or has Shift selection been deemed unergonomical so we have some other, better keyboard-based selection at hand?

Comment: Are you using org-mode?  If so, then:  `(setq org-support-shift-select 'always)`; or `nil` for never; or `t` for *When outside special context*.

Comment: Run `emacs -Q` to verify that shift-selection highlighting works by default. Also check that the variable `shift-select-mode` is non-`nil` when running with your normal configuration.

Comment: @phils, I commend you for your modesty, but could you make this a full blown answer? Yes, with `emacs -Q`, it does work. I'm sorry, although I am utilizing emacs extensively, I had little time to actually _study_ it. So, no matter how noobish my question is, please make it a regular answer with explanation what -Q means and perhaps code snippet to put in `.emacs`.

Comment: Since it apparently works without your init file (`emacs -Q`), narrow the problem down by bisecting your init file (`~/.emacs`) recursively.  I.e., comment out 1/2 of it, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16... You can use command `comment-region` with and without a prefix arg to comment a region of text.

Comment: @Drew, with `.emacs` entirely commented out, the undesired behavior persists, while `emacs -Q` still restores it. Where elsewhere are the initialization files?

Comment: Read `C-h i g (emacs) Init File RET` to learn about the init files Emacs uses. Note also that if the `custom-file` variable is set, then all `M-x customize` changes are stored in that file.

Comment: @phils, thanks, the issue was quite peculiarly caused by my old `.emacs.d`, which I used in Emacs 23 copied for use by Emacs 24. In `.emacs.d/elpa`, there were left over packages, which loaded automatically upon startup, and one of them caused the trouble.

Comment: Good to hear you found the problem. I'll have to get in the habit of sending people to the manual for init-file info, instead of mentioning `~/.emacs`. ;-)  `C-h r i init file RET`. Likewise, `C-h r i custom-file RET`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shift selection is enabled by default in Emacs 24.

You can always run `emacs -Q` to disable your init file and any other default libraries, in order to determine what Emacs' default behaviour is.

You can also run `emacs -q` which will disable only your init file (other system-wide init files can be loaded).

If the feature works without your init file and does not work with it, you can then start to narrow down what part of your init file is at fault (often by commenting out functionality until the feature starts working as expected -- note Drew's comment).

In this case I suggest that you firstly verify (using <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>) that the `shift-select-mode` variable is non-`nil` (when running with your normal configuration), as a `nil` value means that shift selection is disabled.

Comment: Indeed, `C-h v` reports that `shift-select-mode` variable's value is `nil`, whereas original value was `t`. I'll try the init file bisecting method to see who does this unwanted change for me.

Comment: Before doing that, be sure to check whether it's just set directly in your init file (or in your customize file, if it's separate). e.g. updating and saving the value via `M-x customize-variable RET shift-select-mode RET` might be sufficient. Failing that, you might find `M-x rgrep RET shift-select-mode RET *.el RET ~/.emacs.d/ RET` useful for tracking down potential culprits.

Comment: culprits were old packages in `.emacs.d/elpa`. I purged them all and reinstalled only the ones I need. This happened since I reinstalled whole system and simply copied the backuped config files to my home directory.

Answer (score 1):

I also found it useful to look at `load-path` variable, `C-h v load-path`, which directed me to the culprits, old elpa packages.